# Can i work in subdirectories with the system() command?

Tags: c, system

I am some kind of newbie in programming and i was just asking myself, if i can switch between folders with the system() command and work there, just like i can do when i type in the commands in the terminal by myself.

It's not that kind of very important problem, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Why not use [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)?

Comment: Nope. Why are you asking this question? Why not "how can I change folders"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following possibly: `system ("cd /path/to/dir; pwd");` . Which is, separate the commands via a semicolon. Although once the function returns the directory change will not be applicable anymore. This is because the `system` command spawns a new process to execute whatever you have put in the arguments. Once the process terminates things are lost. Therefore, this directory change is applicable to the process which `system` spawns, and *not* to the working directory of the program which calls `system` .

Although, depending on what is your purpose, I would recommend seeing `fork`, `exec` family, and `chdir` in a combination.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help.